# Obtener el tamaño de una columna de Access mediante consulta SQL

Tags: sql, .net

Tengo hipoteticamente una base de datos en Access:

```
TProductos
Nombre del campo // tipo // Tamaño del campo 

    _id : integer(15)
    Descripcion: TEXT(100)
    Nombre: TEXT(100)
```

Como puedo obtener el tamaño del campo Nombre desde una consulta SQL.
Esto es lo que tengo hasta ahora.

```
comando.CommandText = ("Select LENGTH (Descripcion) From TProductos")
```

Comment: En otras palabras, ¿quieres encontrar una consulta que obtenga el valor 100?

Comment: Si , para hacer comprobaciones en el codigo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con este codigo accedes a las propiedades de la tabla:

```
select 
     character_maximum_length    
from 
     information_schema.columns  
where 
     table_name = 'TProductos'
and   
     column_name LIKE 'Nombre'
```